# number of rational points of hyper elliptic curve $y^5=-x^2+x$ over $\Bbb{F}_{121}$

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C$ be a curve given by $y^5=-x^2+x$ defined over  $\overline{\Bbb{F}_{11}}$.

I want to calculate　$\# C(\Bbb{F}_{11})$ and $\# C(\Bbb{F}_{11^2})$.

I calculated $\# C(\Bbb{F}_{11})＝\#\{(0,0),(1,0),(2,±3),(3,±4),(6,±5),(9, ±4),(10,±3),∞\}=13$(where $∞=(1:0:0)$ in projective closure) by my hand.

But I'm stuck with calculating $\# C(\Bbb{F}_{11^2})$.
Maybe there is no method (in other words, theoretical way) to calculate $\# C(\Bbb{F}_{11^2})$ by hand, but calculation **with computer** is also appreciated.

Background. If over $\Bbb{F}_p$ and $5$ does not divide $p-1$, $y \mapsto y^5$ is bijective, so the number of rational point is $p+1$. $p=5$ maybe(if my above counting is correct) a smallest example s.t. $p$ of $\# C(\Bbb{F}_p)\neq p+1$

Comment: I need to think whether there is  a clean way to do this by hand. It is easy to brute force this with Mathematica using $\Bbb{F}_{11^2}\simeq\Bbb{F}_{11}(i)$. It found $102$ affine points. This leads to $-3.04508 \pm 1.31433i$ and $2.54508 \pm 2.12663 i$ as approximate (reciprocal) zeros of the zeta function, and leads to a prediction of $1392$ affine points with coordinates in $\Bbb{F}_{11^3}$ by Hasse-Weil-Davenport. Anyway, you need the tally over both $\Bbb{F}_{11}$ as well as $\Bbb{F}_{11^2}$ to determine those zeros because this is a genus $2$ curve.

Comment: Those zeros are the roots of $x^4+x^3-9x^2+11x+121$.

Comment: Your zeta means congruent zeta function ? Your second comment's polynomial is essentially numerator of congruent zeta of $C$ , $1+Z-9T^2+11T^3+121T^4$ ?

Comment: The quartic factors over $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$ as the product of $x^2+\dfrac{1\pm5\sqrt5}2x+11$.

Comment: Correct. I was only looking at it as a function field/smooth curve over $\Bbb{F}_{11}$.

Comment: Wait a minute! Can't we use the multiplicative character sums of $\Bbb{F}_{11}$ to find the zeros of the congruent zeta function. It seems to me that those four complex zeros are the negatives of the character sums
$$S(\psi)=\sum_{x\in\Bbb{F}_{11}}\psi(-x^2+x),$$ where $\psi$ ranges over the multiplicative characters of order five in $\widehat{\Bbb{F}_{11}^*}$. The sums $S(\psi)$ all have absolute values $\sqrt{11}$ as they are essentially Gauss sums.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The job is easily done with computer support, here [sage](https://www.sagemath.org). Let us do this first.

```
F = GF(11)
R.<x,y,z> = PolynomialRing(F)
C = Curve(y^5 + z^3*(x^2 - x*z))
print(f'C is the curve:\n{C}')
```

We have initialized:

```
C is the curve:
Projective Plane Curve over Finite Field of size 11
defined by y^5 + x^2*z^3 - x*z^4
```

Then in a dialog with the sage interpreter:

```
sage: C.is_singular()
True
sage: C.singular_points()
[(1 : 0 : 0)]

sage: C.L_polynomial()
121*t^4 + 11*t^3 - 9*t^2 + t + 1

sage: C.rational_points()
[(0 : 0 : 1),
 (1 : 0 : 0),
 (1 : 0 : 1),
 (4 : 2 : 1),
 (4 : 6 : 1),
 (4 : 7 : 1),
 (4 : 8 : 1),
 (4 : 10 : 1),
 (8 : 2 : 1),
 (8 : 6 : 1),
 (8 : 7 : 1),
 (8 : 8 : 1),
 (8 : 10 : 1)]
sage: len(C.rational_points())
13
```

To see how many points there are after a quadratic extension...

```
sage: len(C.base_extend(GF(11^2)).rational_points())
103
```

---

So the zeta function of $C$ is
$$
\begin{aligned}
Z(C,T)
&=\exp\left(\sum_k\frac 1k\cdot\#C(\Bbb F_{11^k})\cdot T^k\right)
\\
&=\frac{L(T)}{(1-T)(1-11T)}
\\
&=\frac{1+T-9T^2+11T^3+121T^4}{(1-T)(1-11T)}
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and sage gave the above `L_polynomial` for `C`, so we can extract the cardinalities $\# C(\Bbb F_{11^k})$ for some first $k$ values:

```
sage: R.<T> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ)
....: log( C.L_polynomial()(T) / (1 - T) / (1 - 11*T) ) + O(T^8)
13*T + 103/2*T^2 + 1393/3*T^3 + 14883/4*T^4 + 161448/5*T^5 + 1774963/6*T^6 + 19477303/7*T^7 + O(T^8)
```

So we expect for instance $1393$ points in an extension of degree three of $F$... and indeed, after a long time to compute the enumeration...

```
sage: len(C.base_extend(GF(11^3)).rational_points())
1393
```

---

To do something with bare hands, let us analyze the map $y\to y^5$ on $F=\Bbb F_{11}$ and on $L=\Bbb F_{121}$. Zero is mapped to zero. Else, for $y\ne 0$? We have $y^{10}=1$ on $F$. So $y^5$ is $\pm 1$ for $y\in F$, and each value is taken five times.

The listed points above show that we can realize only $y^5=-1$ (with $y\ne 0$). Observe that if $(x,y)$ satisfies
$$
y^5 =x(1-x)\ ,
$$
then this also holds for $(y,1-x)$. (So if we know the five points $(4,y)$, then we also know the other five point $(1-4,y)=(8,y)$.)

Also, $(x,y)$ point on $C$ immediately gives the points $(x,g^2y)$, $(x,g^4y)$, $(x,g^4y)$, $(x,g^8y)$, where $g$ is a multiplicative generator of $F^\times$. And if $x$ in $F$ or $L$ is a first component of a point, than there are exactly five points of the shape $(x,g^{2k}y)$ having this first component.

```
sage: F
Finite Field of size 11
sage: g = F.multiplicative_generator()
sage: g
2
sage: [g^(2*k) for k in [0..4]]
[1, 4, 5, 9, 3]
```

One can also write $x^2-x=x^2-12x=(x-6)^2-36=(x-6)^2-3$.
Combining the above arguments, the list of points offered by sage above over $F=\Bbb F_{11}$ can be also easily computed with bare hands.

---

What above $L$, the field with $121$ elements? We restrict to finding affine $L$-rational points $(x,y)$ which are not defined over $F$. As seen above, it is enough to find the $x$-values having $x(1-x)$ a fifth power.

Again, with the computer:

```
sage: F = GF(11)
sage: RF.<U> = PolynomialRing(F)
sage: L.<a> = GF(11^2, U^2 + U + 1)
sage: L
Finite Field in a of size 11^2
sage: a.minpoly()
x^2 + x + 1

sage: list(set([x for x in L if (U^5 - x*(1-x)).roots(ring=L)]))
[0,
 1,
 4,
 8,
 a + 1,
 a + 3,
 a + 10,
 2*a + 1,
 2*a + 2,
 4*a + 1,
 4*a + 4,
 5*a + 7,
 5*a + 10,
 6*a + 2,
 6*a + 5,
 7*a,
 7*a + 8,
 9*a,
 9*a + 10,
 10*a,
 10*a + 2,
 10*a + 9]
sage:
```

For the first $x$-values $0,1,4,8$ we know the resulting $13$ $F$-rational points. The next $18$ values of $x$ (which are $9$ pairs of values $x, 1-x$) introduce further $18\cdot 5=90$ rational points. This gives a total of $13+90=103$ points.

---

Is there any chance to proceed in a structural manner?
We already know that the $L$-polynomial is of the shape
$$
L(T)=1 + T + cT^2 + 11T^3 + 121T^4\ .
$$
We have reasons to expect $\# C(\Bbb F_{121})=13 + 2\cdot 5\cdot k$ for some integer $k$. (Using $x\to 1-x$, and $y\to g^{2k}y$.) Also there are bounds for this number:
$$
-2\cdot2\cdot\sqrt{121}\le 121+1\le 2\cdot2\cdot\sqrt{121}\ .
$$
So only $83$, $93$, $103$, $113$, $123$, $133$, $143$, $153$, $163$ can show up. One can now compute the corresponding $c$-values in the $L$-polynomial, and check if the roots have all the right modulus... (But again, doing so i need a computer.)

---

---

*Later EDIT:* "Same question" for the hyperelliptic curve in next genus,
$$
C \ :\qquad y^7 = -x^2 + x\ ,
$$
over the fiels with $p$ and $p^2$ elements, $p$ being the prime $p=29$.

```
p = 29
F = GF(p)
F2 = GF(p^2)

R.<x,y,z> = PolynomialRing(F)
RQ.<T> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ)

C = Curve(y^7 + z^5*(x^2 - x*z))

L = C.L_polynomial()
Z = log( L(T) / (1 - T) / (1 - p*T) )

print(f"F is the field:\n{F}\n")
print(f"F2 is the field:\n{F2}\n")
print(f"C is the curve:\n{C}\n")
print(f"The L-Polynomial of C is:\n{L}\n")
print(f"The Z-function of C is:\n{Z}\n")
print(f"Check for the cardinalities C(F) and C(F2):")
print(f"# C(F)  = {len(C.rational_points())}")
print(f"# C(F2) = {len(C.base_extend(F2).rational_points())}")
```

Results (with manually slightly rearranged output to fit in the MSE band width) after some few minutes:

```
F is the field:
Finite Field of size 29

F2 is the field:
Finite Field in z2 of size 29^2

C is the curve:
Projective Plane Curve over Finite Field of size 29 
defined by y^7 + x^2*z^5 - x*z^6

The L-Polynomial of C is:
24389*t^6 + 841*t^5 - 783*t^4 - 69*t^3 - 27*t^2 + t + 1

The Z-function of C is:
31*T + 787/2*T^2 + 24265/3*T^3 + 702859/4*T^4 + 20513391/5*T^5 
    + 594795463/6*T^6 + 17249583480/7*T^7 + 500244091539/8*T^8
    + 14507146991683/9*T^9 + 420707233574967/10*T^10 
    + 12200509372167609/11*T^11 + 353814782784565987/12*T^12 
    + 10260628712662461255/13*T^13 + 148779116346777556246/7*T^14
    + 575279249814016300549*T^15 
    + 250246473681188954827203/16*T^16 
    + 7257147736729702375185933/17*T^17
    + 210457284365192863709980951/18*T^18
    + 6103261246589707340158433551/19*T^19 + O(T^20)

Check for the cardinalities C(F) and C(F2):
# C(F)  = 31
# C(F2) = 787
```

---

*Later EDIT #2:* And the same code as above, with the following two lines changed, so that we are working with $C$ with affine equation $y^5 =-x^2+x$ in characteristic $p=31$,

```
p = 31
C = Curve(y^5 + z^3*(x^2 - x*z))
```

has the results (also manually changed):

```
F is the field:
Finite Field of size 31

F2 is the field:
Finite Field in z2 of size 31^2

C is the curve:
Projective Plane Curve over Finite Field of size 31 
defined by y^5 + x^2*z^3 - x*z^4

The L-Polynomial of C is:
961*t^4 + 341*t^3 + 61*t^2 + 11*t + 1

The Z-function of C is:
43*T + 963/2*T^2 + 30133/3*T^3 + 919803/4*T^4 + 28638348/5*T^5 
 + 295837381/2*T^6 + 27512900563/7*T^7 
 + 852887808483/8*T^8 + 26439628483153/9*T^9
 + 409814154294599/5*T^10 + 25408477098836743/11*T^11
 + 262554260396916721/4*T^12 + 24417546300228124333/13*T^13
 + 756943935258853246503/14*T^14 + 7821753997315868117516/5*T^15
 + 727423121745279143223843/16*T^16
 + 22550116774161780528174763/17*T^17
 + 233017873333033411054492561/6*T^18
 + 21670662219970398858049959853/19*T^19 + O(T^20)

Check for the cardinalities C(F) and C(F2):
# C(F)  = 43
# C(F2) = 963
```

---

*Later EDIT #3:* As asked in the comments, let $C$ be the curve with affine equation $y^5 =-x^2+x$, we cover all characteristics $p$ up to $p=41$, plot in each case the $L$-polynomial $L_p(T)$, and the first terms in the congruent / congruence zeta function $Z_p(T)=Z(C/\Bbb F_p, T)$ modulo $O(T^6)$. The included information in  the following mathjax / latex `aligned` block was produced by sage, the code is postponed:
$$
\begin{aligned}
L_{2}(T) &= 1 + 4 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{2}(T) &= 3 T + \frac{5}{2} T^{2} + 3 T^{3} + \frac{33}{4} T^{4} + \frac{33}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{3}(T) &= 1 + 9 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{3}(T) &= 4 T + 5 T^{2} + \frac{28}{3} T^{3} + \frac{59}{2} T^{4} + \frac{244}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{5}(T) &= 1\\
\log Z_{5}(T) &= 6 T + 13 T^{2} + 42 T^{3} + \frac{313}{2} T^{4} + \frac{3126}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{7}(T) &= 1 + 49 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{7}(T) &= 8 T + 25 T^{2} + \frac{344}{3} T^{3} + \frac{1299}{2} T^{4} + \frac{16808}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{11}(T) &= 1 +  T - 9 T^{2} + 11 T^{3} + 121 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{11}(T) &= 13 T + \frac{103}{2} T^{2} + \frac{1393}{3} T^{3} + \frac{14883}{4} T^{4} + \frac{161448}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{13}(T) &= 1 + 169 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{13}(T) &= 14 T + 85 T^{2} + \frac{2198}{3} T^{3} + \frac{14619}{2} T^{4} + \frac{371294}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{17}(T) &= 1 + 289 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{17}(T) &= 18 T + 145 T^{2} + 1638 T^{3} + \frac{42339}{2} T^{4} + \frac{1419858}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{19}(T) &= 1 + 38 T^{2} + 361 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{19}(T) &= 20 T + 219 T^{2} + \frac{6860}{3} T^{3} + \frac{64439}{2} T^{4} + 495220 T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{23}(T) &= 1 + 529 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{23}(T) &= 24 T + 265 T^{2} + 4056 T^{3} + \frac{140979}{2} T^{4} + \frac{6436344}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{29}(T) &= 1 + 58 T^{2} + 841 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{29}(T) &= 30 T + 479 T^{2} + 8130 T^{3} + \frac{351959}{2} T^{4} + 4102230 T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{31}(T) &= 1 + 11 T + 61 T^{2} + 341 T^{3} + 961 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{31}(T) &= 43 T + \frac{963}{2} T^{2} + \frac{30133}{3} T^{3} + \frac{919803}{4} T^{4} + \frac{28638348}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{37}(T) &= 1 + 1369 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{37}(T) &= 38 T + 685 T^{2} + \frac{50654}{3} T^{3} + \frac{939819}{2} T^{4} + \frac{69343958}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
L_{41}(T) &= 1 - 9 T + 71 T^{2} - 369 T^{3} + 1681 T^{4}\\
\log Z_{41}(T) &= 33 T + \frac{1743}{2} T^{2} + 23001 T^{3} + \frac{2825563}{4} T^{4} + \frac{115886298}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
\end{aligned}
$$
Used code:

```
RT.<T> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=6)
for p in primes(42):
    R.<x,y,z> = PolynomialRing(GF(p))
    C = Curve(y^5 + z^3*(x^2 - x*z))    # automatically over GF(p)
    L = C.L_polynomial()
    Z = L(T) / (1 - T) / (1 - p*T)
    print(f"L_{{{p}}}(T) &= {latex(L(T))}\\\\")
    print(f"\\log Z_{{{p}}}(T) &= {latex(log(Z))}\\\\[2mm]")
```

---

*Later EDIT #4:* As asked in the comments, let us also cover experimentally the curve $C$ with affine equation $y^2 =(x^2+1)(x^4 - 8x^3 + 2x^2 +8x + 1)$ for some small characteristics. Same code, only the curve is changed. We have a singular curve, so that we do not expect to see an $L$-polynomial of degree equal to doubled genus.
$$
\begin{aligned}
p &= 3\text{ , genus = 0, singular}\\
L_{3}(t) &= 1 - t + t^{2} - t^{3} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 + t^{2})\\
\log Z_{3}(T) &= 3 T + \frac{11}{2} T^{2} + 9 T^{3} + \frac{79}{4} T^{4} + \frac{243}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 5\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{5}(t) &= 1 - t - 6 t^{2} + 6 t^{3} + 25 t^{4} - 25 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 4 t + 5 t^{2}) \cdot (1 + 4 t + 5 t^{2})\\
\log Z_{5}(T) &= 5 T + \frac{13}{2} T^{2} + \frac{125}{3} T^{3} + \frac{653}{4} T^{4} + 625 T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 7\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{7}(t) &= 1 + 7 t + 22 t^{2} + 26 t^{3} - 7 t^{4} - 49 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 + 4 t + 7 t^{2})^{2}\\
\log Z_{7}(T) &= 15 T + \frac{45}{2} T^{2} + 101 T^{3} + \frac{2589}{4} T^{4} + 3267 T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 11\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{11}(t) &= 1 - t - 6 t^{2} + 6 t^{3} + 121 t^{4} - 121 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 6 t^{2} + 121 t^{4})\\
\log Z_{11}(T) &= 11 T + \frac{109}{2} T^{2} + \frac{1331}{3} T^{3} + \frac{15053}{4} T^{4} + \frac{161051}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 13\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{13}(t) &= 1 - t - 22 t^{2} + 22 t^{3} + 169 t^{4} - 169 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 22 t^{2} + 169 t^{4})\\
\log Z_{13}(T) &= 13 T + \frac{125}{2} T^{2} + \frac{2197}{3} T^{3} + \frac{28269}{4} T^{4} + \frac{371293}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 17\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{17}(t) &= 1 + 11 t + 58 t^{2} + 134 t^{3} + 85 t^{4} - 289 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 + 6 t + 17 t^{2})^{2}\\
\log Z_{17}(T) &= 29 T + \frac{285}{2} T^{2} + \frac{4733}{3} T^{3} + \frac{84669}{4} T^{4} + \frac{1416029}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 19\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{19}(t) &= 1 - t - 22 t^{2} + 22 t^{3} + 361 t^{4} - 361 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 22 t^{2} + 361 t^{4})\\
\log Z_{19}(T) &= 19 T + \frac{317}{2} T^{2} + \frac{6859}{3} T^{3} + \frac{130797}{4} T^{4} + \frac{2476099}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 23\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{23}(t) &= 1 - t + 46 t^{2} - 46 t^{3} + 529 t^{4} - 529 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 + 23 t^{2})^{2}\\
\log Z_{23}(T) &= 23 T + \frac{621}{2} T^{2} + \frac{12167}{3} T^{3} + \frac{277725}{4} T^{4} + \frac{6436343}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 29\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{29}(t) &= 1 - t - 54 t^{2} + 54 t^{3} + 841 t^{4} - 841 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 54 t^{2} + 841 t^{4})\\
\log Z_{29}(T) &= 29 T + \frac{733}{2} T^{2} + \frac{24389}{3} T^{3} + \frac{704813}{4} T^{4} + \frac{20511149}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 31\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{31}(t) &= 1 + 7 t + 70 t^{2} + 170 t^{3} + 713 t^{4} - 961 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 + 4 t + 31 t^{2})^{2}\\
\log Z_{31}(T) &= 39 T + \frac{1053}{2} T^{2} + 9725 T^{3} + \frac{923133}{4} T^{4} + \frac{28649799}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 37\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{37}(t) &= 1 - t - 70 t^{2} + 70 t^{3} + 1369 t^{4} - 1369 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 12 t + 37 t^{2}) \cdot (1 + 12 t + 37 t^{2})\\
\log Z_{37}(T) &= 37 T + \frac{1229}{2} T^{2} + \frac{50653}{3} T^{3} + \frac{1869837}{4} T^{4} + \frac{69343957}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 41\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{41}(t) &= 1 + 3 t + 82 t^{2} + 78 t^{3} + 1517 t^{4} - 1681 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 + 2 t + 41 t^{2})^{2}\\
\log Z_{41}(T) &= 45 T + \frac{1837}{2} T^{2} + 22815 T^{3} + \frac{2820317}{4} T^{4} + 23177321 T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 43\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{43}(t) &= 1 - t - 70 t^{2} + 70 t^{3} + 1849 t^{4} - 1849 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 70 t^{2} + 1849 t^{4})\\
\log Z_{43}(T) &= 43 T + \frac{1709}{2} T^{2} + \frac{79507}{3} T^{3} + \frac{3416397}{4} T^{4} + \frac{147008443}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 47\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{47}(t) &= 1 + 15 t + 142 t^{2} + 594 t^{3} + 1457 t^{4} - 2209 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 + 8 t + 47 t^{2})^{2}\\
\log Z_{47}(T) &= 63 T + \frac{2269}{2} T^{2} + 34197 T^{3} + \frac{4886717}{4} T^{4} + \frac{229346623}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 53\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{53}(t) &= 1 - t - 6 t^{2} + 6 t^{3} + 2809 t^{4} - 2809 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 6 t^{2} + 2809 t^{4})\\
\log Z_{53}(T) &= 53 T + \frac{2797}{2} T^{2} + \frac{148877}{3} T^{3} + \frac{7901645}{4} T^{4} + \frac{418195493}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 59\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{59}(t) &= 1 - t - 102 t^{2} + 102 t^{3} + 3481 t^{4} - 3481 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 102 t^{2} + 3481 t^{4})\\
\log Z_{59}(T) &= 59 T + \frac{3277}{2} T^{2} + \frac{205379}{3} T^{3} + \frac{12110477}{4} T^{4} + \frac{714924299}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 61\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{61}(t) &= 1 - t - 86 t^{2} + 86 t^{3} + 3721 t^{4} - 3721 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 86 t^{2} + 3721 t^{4})\\
\log Z_{61}(T) &= 61 T + \frac{3549}{2} T^{2} + \frac{226981}{3} T^{3} + \frac{13845933}{4} T^{4} + \frac{844596301}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
p &= 67\text{ , genus = 2, singular}\\
L_{67}(t) &= 1 - t - 118 t^{2} + 118 t^{3} + 4489 t^{4} - 4489 t^{5} = \left(-1\right) \cdot (-1 + t) \cdot (1 - 118 t^{2} + 4489 t^{4})\\
\log Z_{67}(T) &= 67 T + \frac{4253}{2} T^{2} + \frac{300763}{3} T^{3} + \frac{20141229}{4} T^{4} + \frac{1350125107}{5} T^{5} + O(T^{6})\\[2mm]
\end{aligned}
$$

```
PSR.<T> = PowerSeriesRing(QQ, default_prec=6)
RQ.<t,u> = PolynomialRing(QQ, order='neglex')
for p in primes(3, 70):
    R.<x,y> = PolynomialRing(GF(p))
    Ca = Curve( -y^2 + (x^2 + 1)*(x^4 - 8*x^3 + 2*x^2 + 8*x + 1) )
    C = Ca.projective_closure()    # Ca is affine, C projective.
    L = C.L_polynomial()
    Z = L(T) / (1 - T) / (1 - p*T)
    print(f"p &= {p}\\text{{ , genus = {C.genus()}{', singular' if C.is_singular() else ''}}}\\\\")
    print(f"L_{{{p}}}(t) &= {latex(L(t))} = {latex(L(t).factor())}\\\\")
    print(f"\\log Z_{{{p}}}(T) &= {latex(log(Z))}\\\\[2mm]")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. I'm not familiar with Sage, but noticed it very useful thanks to your answer. For the case $C: y^7=-x^2+x$, what is $\sharp C(\Bbb{F}_{29})$ and $\sharp C(\Bbb{F}_{{29}^2})$ and if possible, what is congruent zeta function of $Z(C/\Bbb{F}_{29}, T)$ ?

Comment: If I could install sage, it's better. But I tried to use 'Sage cell server' , but it does not work well with your code(This is because I'm very bad at using this kind of computer machine).

Comment: I should make myself to be able to use Sage, but at this point, I want to know the result, $p=7$ and over $\Bbb{F}_{29}$ will bring us surprising result I think, and I will comment here if I get the results.

Comment: You can try sage on https://cocalc.com/features/sage - i think. Installing it is not that complicated. There is a community helping in detail - questions are welcome on the asksage platform https://ask.sagemath.org/questions/ . My answer was given just to point to the direction... You had a lot of questions, of rather computational art, or at least where knowing the answer, the explicit number, makes it possible to check a hypothesis and go on. Well, this is a way to proceed. I am working on a linux box, installing sage is just a one-click (or a one terminal command line) far away...

Comment: I will edit the answer, add the wanted information on the hyperelliptic curve $y^7 = -x^2 +x$ over powers of the prime $29$.

Comment: Pasting your code to 'Sage cell server' didn't work . Where am I missing ? For example, after I entered your first code , ''SyntaxError: '(' was never closed'' appears.

Comment: Thank you very much for yourgenerosity. I'm very happy.

Comment: Oh, yes, there is indeed a not closed `Curve(` command, it should have at the end the balancing `)`, just add it manually, please.

Comment: I'm really really sorry, but could you please give me a zeta of the case $y^5=-x^2+x$ over powers of primes $31$ ?  This is last question  I promise and I'll really appreciate you.

Comment: If there are still open question, do not hesitate to ask, we can move the whole discussion to a chat.

Comment: Thank you so much.You are really kind. I would like to know the case curve is $y^2=(x^2+1)(x^4-8x^3+2x^2+8x+1)$ and the field is $\Bbb{F}_3$ and $\Bbb{F}_5$. I want to know the congruent zero of this curve. Jacobian of this curve has CM by $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$, maybe we can find Frobenius which does not come from this CM.

Comment: I added bounty conus to this question. I'll give 50 point to this answer. I really really appreciate you.

Comment: Sorry I calculated $\Bbb{F}_3$ case by hand, then zeta is $\frac{1-T+T^2+3T+9T^4}{(1-T)(1-3T)}$(if I'm correct). If possible, I want the field $\Bbb{F}_5$, $\Bbb{F}_7$.

Comment: I want to know the congruent zeta of  $C:y^2=(x^2+1)(x^4-8x^3+2x^2+8x+1)$ and field is $\Bbb{F}_3$.

Comment: I've added some more experimental data... You are too generous! It is natural for me to share what i know, hope that everybody can see how simple is to use computer aids to complement the dry or the fascinating theoretical play on the computational part with experimental data confirming (or not) the theory and/or the own conjectures...

Comment: Than you so much. For the last curve, this paper states the curve has bad reduction only at p=2,3. Discriminat only has prime factor 2,3. This does not match computational results. Where am I misunderstood？

Comment: Honda theory for formal groups of abelian varieties over Q of GL_2 type, p366, example 2 states the last curve is nonsingular genus 2 curve over Q and only bad at 2,3.

Comment: According to this paper and discriminant, the curve over F_19 should be nonsigular. So numerator of L series should be degree 4‥ Where am I missing？

Comment: Computer input seems to be correct, but discriminat has only prime element 2 and 3 , so it should have good reduction at 19. Thus numerator of L function should be degree 4. I'm very confused.

Comment: sorry to made many comments

Comment: Later EDIT are display error but I don’t know why it occur,sorry for mistake edit.