# Counting the number of points on a curve over a finite field by calculators

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields, algebraic-curves, sagemath, magma

I want to count the number of points on a algebraic curve $C:y^2=x^5-x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{3^n} (n=2,3,4,...)$ by calculators (Pari/GP, Sage, Magma,...).

Can you give me a command that solves the above problem (without relying as much as possible on the fact that $C$ is a hyperelliptic curve) using any calculator you can use?

(Maybe it's just my lack of research, though they do a very good job with this problem for special curves like elliptic curves, but seem to be weak for general $n$ variable plane curves)

Comment: This is a genus two curve, so count (by hand) for $n=1,2$, and the zeta function will do the rest, I think.

Comment: (I am not sure if $n=1,2$ is enough since Frobenius has $2g=4$ eigenvalues.) I understand the idea of computing the congruent zeta function. In fact, I quickly found out that Magma has a command to calculate the congruent zeta function directly. However, I could not find a command that directly solves this question. This seems odd to me, because I would think that if the congruent zeta function can be obtained, then there must be some processing going on in the process that would answer this question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [number of rational points of hyper elliptic curve $y^5=-x^2+x$ over $\Bbb{F}_{121}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4656015/number-of-rational-points-of-hyper-elliptic-curve-y5-x2x-over-bbbf-12)